# Kotlin: scoped functions with try/catch support

Tags: error-handling, kotlin, language-design

I'm working with Kotlin for some time. Compared to Java it's more concise. Still it has some legacy inherited from Java. For example the try-catch-construct. Though it has been upgraded from a [statement in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) to an [expression in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#try-is-an-expression), it's still some kind bulky in writing, assuming we stick to the [officially mentioned code formatter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#configure-style-in-ide) and the code conventions regarding the [control flow statements](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#control-flow-statements).

Then a rather short

```
fun dayOfWeek() : DayOfWeek {
    return try { DayOfWeek.of("1".toInt()) }
    catch (e: NumberFormatException) { logAntThrow(e) }
    catch (e: DateTimeException) { logAntThrow(e) }
}
```

becomes a bulky

```
fun dayOfWeek() : DayOfWeek {
    return try {
       DayOfWeek.of("1".toInt())
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        logAntThrow(e)
    } catch (e: DateTimeException) {
        logAntThrow(e)
    }
}
```

and breaks the code flow.

Trying to follow the design of Kotlin's `run` and `let` I wrote this draft:

```
data class Try<T, B : (T) -> R, R>(
    private val it: T,
    private val block: B,
    private val exceptionHandler: Map<KClass<Exception>, (e: Exception) -> R> = emptyMap()
) : () -> R {

    fun <E : Exception> on(e: KClass<E>, handleException: (e: E) -> R): Try<T, B, R> =
        copy(exceptionHandler = (exceptionHandler.toMap() + (e to handleException)) as Map<KClass<Exception>, (e: Exception) -> R>)

    override fun invoke(): R {
        return try {
            block(it)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            (exceptionHandler[e::class] ?: throw e)(e)
        }
    }

}

typealias TryRun<T, R> = Try<T, T.() -> R, R>
typealias TryLet<T, R> = Try<T, (T) -> R, R>

fun <T, R> T.tryRun(block: T.() -> R): TryRun<T, R> = TryRun(this, block)
fun <T, R> T.tryLet(block: (T) -> R): TryLet<T, R> = TryLet(this, block)
```

Motivation:

- Declaring `TryRun` and `TryLet` makes the use cases explicit. Additionally it defines the generic type parameter `B` of `Try` and provides thus an easier way to use than `Try` itself.
- I choose to declare a function named `on` rather than `catch`. In my opinion it reads better within the code flow. It implies the fact of catching an `Exception` but shifts the focus on the corresponding behavior.
- The declaration of `on` provides a usage following the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). But it doesn't change the internal state, it creates every time a new `Try` instance and thus doesn't use [side-effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect).
- Using the [`invoke` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#invoke-operator) we can finish the building process without calling an additional named function. Everything in between is the parametrization of this call.

Some examples following the code conventions on [wrapping chained calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#wrap-chained-calls) and [lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#lambdas).

```
fun main() {

    // succeeds - only happy path
    "1".tryLet { DayOfWeek.of(it.toInt()) }()
        .let { println("Day Of Week is: $it") }

    "1".tryRun { DayOfWeek.of(toInt()) }()
        .let { println("Day Of Week is: $it") }

    // succeeds - provding two cases of exception handling
    "5".tryRun { DayOfWeek.of(toInt()) }
        .on(NumberFormatException::class) {
            log(it)
            DayOfWeek.MONDAY
        }.on(DateTimeException::class) {
            log(it)
            DayOfWeek.MONDAY
        }()
        .let { println("Day Of Week is: $it") }

    // fails with DateTimeException - (re)throws the exception
    "0".tryRun { DayOfWeek.of(toInt()) }()
        .let { println("Day Of Week is: $it") }

    // fails with DateTimeException - returns SUNDAY as default value
    "0".tryLet { DayOfWeek.of(it.toInt()) }
        .on(NumberFormatException::class) {
            log(it)
            DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
        }.on(DateTimeException::class) {
            log(it)
            DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
        }()
        .let { println("Day Of Week is : $it") }

    // fails with NumberFormatException - returns null as default value
    "five".tryLet { DayOfWeek.of(it.toInt()) }
        .on(NumberFormatException::class) {
            log(it)
            null
        }.on(DateTimeException::class) {
            log(it)
            null
        }()
        .let { println("Day Of Week is : $it") }

    // fails with NumberFormatException - explicitly re-throws the exception
    "six".tryLet { DayOfWeek.of(it.toInt()) }
        .on(NumberFormatException::class) {
            logAntThrow(it)
        }.on(DateTimeException::class) {
            logAntThrow(it)
        }()
        .let { println("Day Of Week is : $it") }

}

fun log(entry: Any) = println(entry)

fun logAntThrow(e: Exception): Nothing {
    log(e)
    throw e
}
```

This is a draft and intended for first feedback. It is e.g. missing support for the `finally` case and doesn't take inheritance into account determining an exception handler.

Any hints / ideas ?

Comment: `logAntThrow`... those poor ants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Consider options

You should consider looking at Kotlin's existing [runCatching](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run-catching.html) and the Arrow library's [either](https://apidocs.arrow-kt.io/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/index.html).

A lot of what you are trying to accomplish already exists either built-in inside Kotlin or in a popular library.

#### Your code

I think that this code feels weird:

```
"0".tryRun { DayOfWeek.of(toInt()) }()
    .let { println("Day Of Week is: $it") }
```

And it is clearer to write it as one of the following:

```
runCatching { DayOfWeek.of("0") }.fold(onSuccess = { println(it) }, onFailure = { throw it })
runCatching { DayOfWeek.of("0") }.onSuccess { println(it) }.getOrThrow()
```

---

Additionally, your code creates a bit of overhead by creating instances of `Try` **and** multiple `Map` instances for every `tryRun`/`tryLet` that you do.

#### Multi-catch

I notice that all your `catch` statements seem to do the same thing at the moment, if that will be the case then you might want to consider catching a more generic exception. Even if you want to handle exceptions differently, you could get some inspiration from [an article on how you would do multi-catch in Kotlin](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/catch-multiple-exceptions) using the when-statement.

#### Side-note

As a side note, I think that your comparison of "Then a rather short" ... "becomes a bulky" is a bit unfair, as the first example (the "rather short" one) also doesn't match any [Java coding conventions that I am familiar with](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I'm working with Kotlin 1.8. I wasn't aware of `runCatching`. I wouldn't bother to design my draft, knowing that there is already an out-of-the-box solution. It's like reinventing the wheel. The "rather short" code was an attempt to write the try-catch-syntax in a possible shorter way. Since it is already Kotlin code, I wasn't comparing it to Java. That would indeed be unfair.

Comment: @LuCio No one is forcing you to follow all the Kotlin code standards everywhere, so you can go ahead and use the "rather short" version if you want to. Be pragmatic :)

Comment: I've read the "article on how you would do multi-catch in Kotlin". Seems they were also missing a more sophisticated way to handle different exceptions. I wasn't that far from it defining my `on` function. Maybe I would end up with something like that, if I have been aware of `runCatching`.

Comment: @LuCio Yes, using `when`-statements like they do in the article has the benefit of not requiring to instantiate any maps. If you have any other Kotlin concerns that you might need, you can usually find me in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/coding-projects-and-mtg-heaven) (which is also where I have a feed so that I could find your question)

Comment: I think they shouldn't have named it `runCatching` as it's easy to confuse it with `runBlocking`. I thought it's a coroutine, but it isn't! I wish it was called something different like `executeCatching` or even better `tryCaching`.

Comment: @t3chb0t This also applies to me. I am working with Kotlin for over a year and was now looking for a function called something like "try...". I didn't find anything. Therefore my draft :)

Comment: @t3chb0t Naming it `tryCatching` would make sense, but I think that there's not that much confusion between `runCatching` and `runBlocking` - just think of the difference between catch and block. In sports they might be similar, but not in code :)

Comment: This question & review couldn't have a better timing. I just needed to validate user input in my desktop app and `Either` solves this so nicely ;-D